# How to select changed modified date of an item in t-sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, tfs

I'm trying to get a report of Work Items which their Due Date is postponed. I have access to Tfs_Warehouse database which has a table named DimWorkItem. In this table TFS keeps all the history of every item. So my data is like this;

```
System_Id | DueDate
-------------------------------
  6130    | 2014-02-13 00:00:00.000
  6130    | 2014-02-13 00:00:00.000
  6130    | 2014-03-06 00:00:00.000
  6130    | 2014-03-11 00:00:00.000
  6130    | 2014-03-11 00:00:00.000
  6130    | 2014-03-21 00:00:00.000
  6131    | 2014-03-11 00:00:00.000
  6131    | 2014-03-11 00:00:00.000
  6131    | 2014-03-11 00:00:00.000
```

I need to write such a query that, query should return the System_Id's which their `DueDate` has been postponed to further date.

So query should return only System_Id = 6130

Thank you in advance,

Comment: This is not very clear - what's special about the dates associated with 6130 that you're looking to select on?

Comment: Have you tried CurrentWorkItem view?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT System_Id
FROM (
    SELECT System_Id, DueDate, RANK()OVER(PARTITION BY System_Id ORDER BY DueDate) AS Ranking
    FROM TFS_Warehouse
    ) Z
WHERE Ranking > 1
```

Results:

```
6130
```

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding correctly, another way of stating the problem is finding the System_ids that have at least two different DueDates associated with them.  If that's the case, try this:

```
select w.System_id, count(w.DueDate) DateCount
from Tfs_Warehouse w 
group by w.System_id
having COUNT(distinct w.DueDate) > 1
```

Comment: I think you're going to want 
select w.System_id
from Tfs_Warehouse w 
group by w.System_id
having COUNT(distinct DueDate) > 1

Comment: Probably a good idea to include distinct in the count, but in my tests it didn't make a difference.

Answer (score 0):

```
select System_ID
from (
    select System_ID 
        , count(DueDate) as Dates
    from DimWorkItem
    group by System_ID
) z 
where dates>1
```